# Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed when I create a table

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have two SQL query's, when I write the second query it drops a SQL error, like this "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed". And I don't know, the first table have ID with primary key.

```
CREATE TABLE clients(
    id_client INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(32),
    surname VARCHAR(32),
    dni VARCHAR(32),
    address VARCHAR(32),
    type CHAR
)
```

And the other:

```
CREATE TABLE clients_vehicles(
    id_client_vehicle INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    license_plate VARCHAR(32),
    num_chasis VARCHAR(32),
    color VARCHAR(32),
    brand VARCHAR(32),
    model VARCHAR(32),
    model_version VARCHAR(32),
    fuel_type CHAR,
    km INT,
    cv INT,
    type CHAR,
    id_client INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (id_client) REFERENCES clients(id_client)
)
```

Comment: `INT` <> `UNSIGNED`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`clients_vehicles.id_client` is `INT` whereas `clients.id_client` is `UNSIGNED INT`. There is type mismatch.

change `UNSIGNED INT` to `INT` and it will work